# How do I ignore folders and files when pushing to Heroku with a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a `Rails 3.2.8` application and I don't want to push my `spec` folder and `test` log to Heroku. How would I do this? What about with a `staging` remote?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could put them in `.gitignore`, but that will exclude them from your repository as a whole.

The better solution is to push them to Heroku but prevent Heroku from deploying them to your dynos. You can configure that with a [`.slugignore` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore).

Comment: Can I do the same with config and database files as they differ on production and staging and I want to be able to push from staging to production but without those files?

Comment: Is "dyno" simply another word for "server?"

Comment: "Dyno" specifically refers to Heroku's unit of execution, which is a Linux container running a single command. Saying "server" instead would carry many incorrect connotations. (For example, a server lives an arbitrarily long time, a server tries to retain the contents of its disks, and administrators can log into a server to perform tasks. On the other hand,  Heroku dynos live at most 24 hours, discard their contents, and you cannot control a running dyno, though you can start a separate `sh` dyno.) See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos for a first-party definition of "dyno".

Comment: Do you know if there's any established convention for where extraneous files in a rails app should go? For example, if I include some images that have no relevance to the app itself in a `README.md` with something like `<img src="readme_notes/titus.png">`, where should I put those images inside the rails app? I have wondered this for a long time

Comment: Answering my own question here, but I see many apps have a folder called `/doc` or `/docs`. Example [here](https://doc.scalingo.com/platform/app/slugignore), and [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).