# How can I add different files to heroku and different to github?

Tags: git, heroku

I got some files .scss which I will compile to .css. My problem is that I want to push to the github the .scss files and to heroku only .css files. I know that I can use .gitignore but it will ignore these files to both Github and Heroku.

Since I am not very familiar with Heroku and I cannot find the answer to my question I'm asking you to help me get rid of this trouble.
I will highly appreciate your effort.

**EDIT:** Even if I use the .slugignore it will ignore only certain files **so for instance ignoring .scss files will not add the .scss files to a Heroku app. (OK that is good, because I need only .css**), but when I add the .css files to .gitignore ( because I do not need the .css files on the Github) **it will prevent deploying the .css files to Heroku**.

Comment: Somebody else might know how to do this, I don't. ..but why not just upload the scss as well? It won't hurt anything and the files are small.

Comment: @pixelfairy I feel like it is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ignore folders and files when pushing to Heroku with a Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523435/how-do-i-ignore-folders-and-files-when-pushing-to-heroku-with-a-rails-app)